# Como trocar dois botões de lugar?

Tags: android, android-layout

Eu estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo Android que é basicamente um jogo. Numa das Activities há alguns botões, e eu queria que quando um evento ocorresse (podendo ser inclusive o gatilho de outro botão) dois botões trocassem de posição no layout. Pesquisei sobre a documentação da classe Transition para ver se era possível utilizar de uma animação para fazer essa troca, mas eu realmente queria algo com um delay inexistente.

OBS: Apenas mudar a aparência dos botões não são opções pra mim, uma vez que cada um desses botões possuem funções diferentes dentro do aplicativo e eu preciso mantê-las.

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/lytKeyboard"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/lytKeyboardLine1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="1"
                android:textSize="50sp"/>

            <Button android:id="@+id/btn2"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="2"
                android:textSize="50sp"/>

            <Button android:id="@+id/btn3"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="3"
                android:textSize="50sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/lytKeyboardLine2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button android:id="@+id/btn4"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="4"
                android:textSize="50sp"/>

            <Button android:id="@+id/btn5"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="5"
                android:textSize="50sp"/>

            <Button android:id="@+id/btn6"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="6"
                android:textSize="50sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/lytKeyboardLine3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button android:id="@+id/btn7"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="7"
                android:textSize="50sp"/>

            <Button android:id="@+id/btn8"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="8"
                android:textSize="50sp"/>

            <Button android:id="@+id/btn9"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="9"
                android:textSize="50sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button android:id="@+id/btn0"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="50sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Coloque na pergunta o xml do layout. Quando diz trocar refere-se a que o botão1 vá para o lugar do botão 2 e o botão 2 para o lugar do botão 1?

Comment: Sim, exatamente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use um GridLayout para dispor os botões.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lytKeyboard"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <GridLayout android:id="@+id/lytKeyboardGrid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:rowCount="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <!--linha 1-->
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"/>

        <Button android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="2"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"/>

        <Button android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="3"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="2"/>

        <!--linha 2-->
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="4"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"/>

        <Button android:id="@+id/btn5"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="5"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="1"/>

        <Button android:id="@+id/btn6"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="6"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="2"/>

        <!--linha 3-->
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn7"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="7"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="0"/>

        <Button android:id="@+id/btn8"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="8"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="1"/>

        <Button android:id="@+id/btn9"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="9"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="2"/>
    </GridLayout>

    <Button android:id="@+id/btn0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:onClick="onClickBtn0"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Se tiver sido indicado, nos parâmetros de cada botão, a linha e coluna que ocupam na grelha, basta fazer a troca desses parâmetros.

```
private void swapButtons(@IdRes int firstButtonId, @IdRes int secondButtonId) {

    Button firstButton;
    Button secondButton;
    try {
        firstButton = findViewById(firstButtonId);
        secondButton = findViewById(secondButtonId);

    }catch(ClassCastException e){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Um ou os dois argumentos não são ID's do tipo Button", e);
    }

    GridLayout firstButtonParent;
    GridLayout secondButtonParent;
    try {
        firstButtonParent = (GridLayout) firstButton.getParent();
        secondButtonParent = (GridLayout) secondButton.getParent();
    }catch (ClassCastException e){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                "Um ou os dois botões não estão num GridLayout", e);
    }

    if(firstButtonParent != secondButtonParent){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
            "Os dois botões não estão no mesmo GridLayout");
    }

    GridLayout.LayoutParams firstButtonParameters =
            (GridLayout.LayoutParams) firstButton.getLayoutParams();
    GridLayout.LayoutParams secondButtonParameters =
            (GridLayout.LayoutParams) secondButton.getLayoutParams();

    firstButton.setLayoutParams(secondButtonParameters);
    secondButton.setLayoutParams(firstButtonParameters);
}
```

Exemplo de uso onde o botão `Btn0`, quando clicado, troca de lugar os `btn2`e `btn5`:

```
public void onClickBtn0(View view) {
    swapButtons(R.id.btn2, R.id.btn5);
}
```

Comment: Era isso que eu queria, obrigado. Na verdade, do jeito que eu planejei o botão 0 também poderia ser trocado de lugar com outro botão, mas é só colocá-lo dentro do GridLayout e eu creio que vai funcionar.